How do I display latex-style math on squarespace?
I want to display latex-style math on my squarespace site.
I'm having trouble finding resources for this. One of the best seems to be this other stackoverflow post, but it's been 7 years since the last activity, and none of the answers seem to work for me.
I expect this is because squarespace keeps changing how they do things. Does anyone here know how to get latex-style math working on their squarespace site?
To be precise, since cdn.mathjax.org is dead, I've only tried the second answer's suggestion, which is to put the suggested code in my website's footer, which I did as suggested by squarespace. I then add a html code block on my page, with the code
 <p>Hello, World! testing latex $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$</p>

but unfortunately the mathcal doesn't render.

You should check if you have referenced MathJax CDN correctly (here's the Documentation).
For example, base on what you provided, you can add this script in your footer (you can find this in Settings > Advanced > Code Injection > Footer):
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
  },
  svg: {
    fontCache: 'global'
  }
};
</script>


What does the line "inlinemath" mean? Are you setting the special characters to be $ and \(...\)? (i.e., $\mathcal{M}$ and ((\mathcal{M})) would both render the mathcal?)

Somehow I got the solution suggested in anandsun's answer here to work, but I have to use "(" and ")" to get it to typeset math. Is that the default "escape" characters? I'm a bit confused since these characters don't appear at all in his suggested code injection.


inlineMath specifies the delimiters used for inline math just as its name. You are correct that I'm setting those 2 special characters to render the same math symbol.



Parenthesises are not standard delimiters as I know. You might have configured MathJax to intepret single parentheses as delimiters for inline math somewhere.
Looking at anandsun's answer, he/she seems to use MathJax 2.7, which has default LaTeX delimiters for inline and block math, and one of those defaults is indeed \(...\) for inline math. And since you are using the $ in markdown, it might intepret it in a different way. You may fix this by adding this to anandsun's script:


I've just realized I can't write script block in comment, but hope you can still see this.
`
`